# How To Get NON-Duplicate Values using Zend DB model?

Tags: php, zend-framework

**fetchresultsAction**

```
  public function fetchresultsAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    //$form_data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    //$examcatID = $form_data['examcatID'];
    $examID = 'Exam_ID_001';
    $Exam_Results = new Admin_Model_Examresults();
    $results = $Exam_Results->fetchExamResults($examID);

    foreach ($results as $value) {
        print_r($value['subjectID']);
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}
```

**Model > Examresults**

```
public function fetchExamResults($examID) {

    $sel = $this->select();
    $sel->distinct();


    $sel->where('examID=?', $examID);
    $result = $this->fetchAll($sel);   // fetch the rows to the array called result

    return $result;
}
```

This Code is not work.I need have to get NON-Duplicate values of subjectID from mysql database.How Can I do that.Please help me to solve this problem.

Note : This is Zend 1.12 version

Comment: are you joining two tables. what is the value you want get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `print_r($value->subjectID)`